# Has SpaceX published a Mars mission profile?

Tags: spacex, mars

Has SpaceX published a Mars mission profile, or any detail of what is supposed to happen after people land on Mars? I know that Elon Musk has said that his goal is to ferry people and supplies from Earth to Mars. However, he has also said that his goal is to spark Mars settlement. Does SpaceX have a plan for producing a viable Mars settlement?

Comment: SpaceX builds the transport system. Elon argued that once going there is possible and affordable others will take it from there.

Comment: Thanks, Roman Reiner. I am checking on the off chance that Mr. Musk might have changed his mind since making those comments.